# What is the alternative of Pivot Control in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am migrating my Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Universal Apps. I am currently working on Windows 8.1 project.In my Windows Phone 8 app , I used Pivot Control to show multiple pages and for each App bar was different and in that when I used to slide the other view was visible. I showed different listbox on each page and the values comes from database. I want to do the same for Windows 8.1 but I found that there is not a Pivot Control in Windows 8.1. Can anyone suggest me any control using which I can do that. If possible explain me with some code.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [XAML controls comparison between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Not all controls are available for both Windows and Windows Phone. Specifically, there is no direct analogue to the Pivot on Windows 8.1. You will need to either redesign your UI to use a different control or write your own (or find a 3rd party control) Pivot control.

Two likely options are a FlipView or a Hub Control, but the specifics will really depend on the details of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will Hub Control help me to acheive my need which I have described in my question?

Comment: It depends on your exact need. The Hub's behaviour isn't exactly the same as the Pivot, so you'll need to change your design a bit to use it. You'll have to determine if it makes sense for your use or not.